# Raspberry Pi 3B+ in endless loop boot on SSD

Tags: boot-issues, raspberry-pi-os

I installed 2021-10-30-raspios-bullseye-arm64-lite on my SSD. The booted, ran through some common options with **raspi-config**, like localization. Rebooted, as requested.

Then I did a **sudo apt update**, and a **sudo apt upgrade**. Rebooted. I didn't do much then, but had to shut it down, for other reasons, so did a **sudo shutdown -h now**.

Later I wanted to reboot, but got in an endless loop. I know very little about Linux, so here's the text on boot, where it loops:

```
Starting helper to synchronize boot up for ifupdown...
Finished helper to synchronize boot up for ifupdown.
Checking in progress on 1 disk(counting from 0 to 100%)
Then the system rboots, and gets stuck in the same place.
```

So I tried downloading 2021-10-30-raspios-bullseye-arm64-lite again, although it runs great on a SD-card. But first I tried creating a FAT32 partition on Windows, checked the disk with Hard Disk Sentinel (84% health and no errors), ran a dos **chkdsk**, then, ran a trim via O&O Defrag. I then booted on the RPI, did 2 reboots, and 2 shutdowns. No issues.

Then did the usual stuff with first boot in **raspi-config** on the RPI, and finished with sudo apt update, and a sudo apt upgrade. Then rebooted.

I then tried 2 additional reboots, with no issues. Then I did a sudo shutdown -h now. Unplugged the supply, and the error returns.

So the error lies within the apt upgrade, and with a following full shutdown.

Comment: It's not a SD card, it's a SSD.

Comment: [OK............](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_lPJ9J-6vDw). lol