# Very slow USB flash drive on Raspberry Pi 3B+

Tags: raspbian, usb, raspberry-pi-os

Here are a few tests with an older Verbatim micro SD-card and the flash drive.

```
# write speed test:
sudo dd if=dev/zero of=temp.txt bs=1M count=1024 oflag=direct
# Read speed test:
sudo dd if=temp.txt of=dev/null bs=1M count=1024 iflag=direct
```

Verbatim SD speed test

Write

1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB, 1.0 GiB) copied, 95.4491 s, 11.2 MB/s

Read

1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB, 1.0 GiB) copied, 47.077 s, 22.8 MB/s

Kingston Datatraveler Kyson 64 GB speed test

Write

1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB, 1.0 GiB) copied, 151.814 s, 7.1 MB/s

Read

1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB, 1.0 GiB) copied, 66.7213 s, 16.1 MB/s

So that's not a huge difference, although the USB should be much faster. But with a clean installation of Raspbian Lite, the problems starts to show up. First doing an apt update and then apt upgrade, the upgrade takes 4 minutes on the Verbatim, but 1½ hours on the USB.

Then installing OpenMediaVault with

```
sudo wget -O - https://github.com/OpenMediaVault-Plugin-Developers/installScript/raw/master/install | sudo bash
```

takes 15 minutes on the SD, but more than 2 hours on the USB. Clearly something is wrong.

Setup:

Raspian Lite, OpenMediaVault & Plex server.

I can stream a 60 GB video, with a combined audio & video stream of 15 Mbit/s, and another 20 GB video to my units, with a Raspberry 3B+, the Verbatim SD card, and an old 2,5" 750 GB harddisk in an USB-to-harddisk enclosure. But I can hardly stream one tiny 2 GB 1 hour video (3 Mbit/s) via the USB flash as OS.

I know, that using the USB along with the 50 GB HD on USB, have to share the bandwith of the USB ports, but still...

Both the micro SD and the USB flash has been tested twice, with complete reinstallation of the OS,  OpenMediaVault & Plex.

Any suggestions? Is this a driver issue of some sort? I'm a noob with Linux.

Comment: The `dd` output is reasonable -- the top read speed on USB 2.0 ports, at least for pre-4 models, is probably ~15 MB/s, which is about half the theoretical limit sometimes given of 30 MB/s (240 mbps, half of the hardware limit).  Anyway, I don't think I've seen anyone claim they will do better than that, meaning a decent SD card will always be ~50% faster.  (ie. if you were hoping putting the root fs on USB would be advantageous, you thought wrong). However, what you are reporting with the task times is much slower than that, which is perplexing.

Comment: My issue isn't that it's a bit slower, but that it's very slower. And that it's unusable as a Plex server. Besides,  I don't get why an USB drive with 3.2 generation speed on a 480 Mbit/s USB gen 2 port should run that slow. And with a USB-to-2,5" HDD encosure, and an 8 year old Kingston SSD, I can get speeds of 27,8 MB/s write, and 28,5 MB/s read. The reason for using an USB flash drive, was because SD cards are said to fail way more often.

Comment: So I also tried to get it to work with the SSD, but ran into this issue: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/135060/raspberry-pi-3b-in-endless-loop-boot-on-ssd

Comment: *"I don't get why an USB drive with 3.2 generation speed on a 480 Mbit/s USB gen 2 port should run that slow."*  Right, but that 480 Mbits/s is the hardware speed.  It's how fast you could transmit an arbitrary signal over the wire.  This is quite a bit more than the amount of actual data payload that can be carried within the USB protocol, the overhead of which is not included in speed tests because it isn't user data...

Comment: In the end, I think you will find [(example)](https://www.premiumusb.com/blog/usb-20-vs-usb-30-speed-test-results) the realistic read speed of USB 2.0 (on a Pi or elsewhere) is 15-20 MB/s.   That's what I meant when I said there is nothing out of line about the `dd` test.  **But I agree with you** that what you are saying about the task time with the root fs is clearly no where near 15 MB/s...

Comment: ...I've been using Pi's for ~9 years and put a USB HD on my first model B and most of the ones since then, and although I've never used it for the root fs (that seems counter productive), the read transfer speed is generally 10-15 MB/s.  So something is wrong in your case (which is why all this isn't an answer).    **You should have a look in the system logs**, eg., try `dmesg` during a transfer.

Comment: There's clearly a problem, when a 10 minutes task sudo apt upgrade) takes +2 hours. The only warning I see in the boot log is "The driver for the USB controller dwc_otg_hcd does not support scatter-gather which is required by the UAS driver. Please try an other USB controller if you wish to use UAS.". Running lsusb -t, I can see that my SSD and USB flash both reports "Driver=usb-storage". But as you see, the SSD is much faster, although the USB-stick supports 200 Mbit/s read.

Comment: Could be there is something weird about the flash drive.  I've been using linux since before USB thumb drives existed and never had a problem -- USB storage is a standardized public protocol and so devices implementing it don't require a make/model specific driver.  But some manufacturers don't follow the standards (eg. gaming mice) and instead distribute devices with custom drivers for Windows/Mac.  **You should put the make and model of the stick in the question.**